# Can I abort the current running bash command?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to manually abort the currently running bash command? So, for example, I'm using 'find' but it's taking ages... how do I manually stop it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Some things won't respond to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>; in that case, you can also do <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> which stops the process and then `kill %1` - or even `fg` to go back to it. Read the section in `man bash` entitled "JOB CONTROL" for more information. It's very helpful. (If you're not familiar with `man` or the man `pager`, you can search using `/`. `man bash` then inside it `/JOB CONTROL`<kbd>Enter</kbd> will start searching, <kbd>n</kbd> will find the next match which is the right section.)

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` is extremely powerful. Use it to put a task in 'suspend' mode. You can then use `fg` to bring the task to the foreground again (just as it was running before), or you can use `bg` to put the task in to the background (just like if you had launched the command using a `&` at the end). See http://linuxreviews.org/beginner/jobs/

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for "CTRL+Z & kill %1" ?

Comment: @Chris Morgan - If a command is running, should it be stopped in midst? This isn't specific to a runaway process. The use case i'm am referring to a `find` command that is searching across `/`. Assuming it's taking longer than anticipated, should it be stopped? Can it in any way result in corrupt the filesystem?

Comment: @Motivated: it depends on the process and how you stop it. In short, SIGTERM (which asks the program to terminate) *should* be completely safe in all software, and that’s the default for `kill`. SIGKILL (which forcibly terminates the program), less so, though it should still be fine at almost any point in almost all software (well-behaved software will perform mutations atomically). Something like `find` doesn’t modify things unless you tell it to (e.g. `-delete`), so killing it forcibly is fine.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - To clarify, is `CTRL+C` a `SIGTERM`? What do you mean by `well-behaved software will perform mutations atomically`?

Comment: Ctrl+C is SIGINT, actually. Likewise it *should* be safe. By performing mutations atomically, I mean not this exaggerated scenario: when you open a file, it deletes it from disk, and then on exit saves the current state of it, leaving a period of time where crashing will lose data; but rather, that any modifications will either be present, or not present, but not a broken intermediate state. Or database transactions: you’ll get all of the transaction, or none of it, and not part of it.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, so this is the order:

1st try: `Ctrl+c`

2nd try: `Ctrl+z`

3rd: login to another console, find the process of the command within your first console that is not responding to both previously mentioned abort/sleep keystrokes with: `ps aux`

Then kill the process with: `kill -9 <PROCESSID>`

Of course there may be smarter parameters to the ps command or the possibility to grep , but this would complicate the explanation.

Comment: The 3rd option did it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to send `SIGINT` to the command to attempt to interrupt it.